# Swift2 how to disable remote notification GCM

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, swift2, ios9

I am developing and app with GCM and remote notification from server. And i want to have UISwitch to disable and enable that action.
I tried something like this but don't know next step.

```
let notificationType = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()!.types
if notificationType != UIUserNotificationType.None {
   print("disabled")
   //what to do here?
} else {
   print("enabled")
   //what to do here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `deleteToken()` or `deleteID()` method to unregister or unsubscribe your device from the GCM, you can read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription) for more details.

*InstanceID deleteToken() with audience set to the app server's sender ID and scope set to GCM. This stops messages (including topic messages) from a specific app server*

*InstanceID deleteID(). This stops messages from all previous registrations and topic subscriptions for all app servers*

sample code:

deleteID:

```
   GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().deleteIDWithHandler { 
       (error: NSError) -> Void in

   }
```

DeleteToken:

```
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().deleteTokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM) { 
      (error: NSError) -> Void in

    }
```